# How to return value from onComplete Success case with parallel queries with spark and scala to build DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

How can I return value from onComplete Success case so I can print hello value?

Currently, I am successfuly getting the query response with right value  and I can process it within the onComplete Success case so I can print correct resp value.

```
import ing.wbaa.druid.SQLQuery

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}


implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val query = SQLQuery(s"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN ('someString', 'someString2')")

val hello = executeQuery(query)
println(hello)

def executeQuery(foo: SQLQuery) = {
    foo.execute.onComplete {
      case Success(resp) => {
        println(resp)
        resp
      }
      case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

The reason is that I may have a List of Strings instead of single String so I would like to do:

```
queryList = List("someString1", ..., "someStringN")
val splitted: List[List[String]] = queryList.grouped(1000).toList
val temp = splittedQueryList.par
temp.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(10))
val hello = temp.map(x => executeQuery(query, x)).seq
```

but hello gets not values but () instead.

You may still ask why do I want to return from onComplete? Because I want to build spark DataFrame out of the responses received.

Comment: your custom query execution will run on driver & It might fail with memory issues. Instead of this approach, You can use spark to execute your queries and then union all dataframe at end.

Comment: so how to make spark to execute multiple queries == how to make spark to call these multiple objects that are in fact query executors?

Comment: I see you are trying to query ```druid``` data, may be check this jdbc ```org.apache.calcite.avatica```  library to connect druid directly from spark.

Comment: ```spark.read.format("jdbc")
.options(
    Map(
        "url" -> "jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://mydruidbroker:8082/druid/v2/sql/avatica/", 
        "dbtable" -> "table_name", 
        "driver" -> "org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver", 
        "fetchSize"->"10000"
    )
).load()```

Comment: @Srinivas I looked into Avatica before I decided to move to Scruid. I was unable query Druid with sql string. I want to send specific query to Druid so it can return result to me. Anyway, we are going sideway away from my main question.

Comment: Exectuing this logic in driver you can get limited threads..also load will not be distributed.. move your logic to executors so that you can use many executors and also less chances of memory issues.

Comment: cool, I will move my logic to executors. How can I do this?

Comment: Which version spark are you using ?? Write Custom data source like jdbc

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of `onComplete` has `Unit` return type, take a loot at it's signature:

```
def onComplete[U](@deprecatedName('func) f: Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

The purpose of `onComplete` is to add callbacks for `success` and `failure` branches of the `Future` evaluation. The `onComplete` purpose is not to make something with *Future success value own*, it's more about to add some processing in case of result **type** (NOT value): `Success` or `Failure`.

`map` function is more suitable for your purpose to use some *successful* result from `Future`. It will change result value to something that you need without losing asynchrony. In scala, `Future` is usually used for asynchronous processing and the final result is usually getting *"in the end of the world"* using

```
Await.result(yourFuture, timeOutLimit) //it will return Future value.
```

So, if you want to process some sequence of queries to database, handle them sequentially and get some sequence of results. This technique is named - *Future composition*.

I would like propose you the better way to do it:

1. use `map` function in `Future` for map some result of query to db to your expected type. Change `executeQuery` signature to return `Future[ResultType]`
2. wrap `temp.map(x => executeQuery(query, x))` by `Future.sequence` function to make queries sequentially and transform `Seq[Future[ResultType]]` to `Future[Seq[ResultType]]`.
3. process `Future[Seq[ResultType]]` using `map` function also to get final result `YourResultTypeProcessingType`.

Your code should looks like below:

```
def executeQuery(foo: SQLQuery): Future[ResultType] = {
  val future = foo.execute.map {
    resp =>
      println(resp)
      resp
  }
  // if you want to print failure exceptions, but I would prefer to use `recoverWith` function to handle failures.
  future.onFailure{
    case ex => ex.printStackTrace()
  }
  future
}

val helloFuture = executeQuery(query)
println(helloFuture)

queryList = List("someString1", ..., "someStringN")
val splitted: List[List[String]] = queryList.grouped(1000).toList
val temp = splittedQueryList.par
temp.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(10))
val hellosFuture = Future.sequence(temp.map(x => executeQuery(query, x)))

def doSmth(value: Seq[ResultType]): YourResultTypeProcessingType = ???

hellosFuture.map{
  successHellosList =>
    doSmth(successHellosList)
}
```

helpful links to understanding scala futures:

- [scala future overview official](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)
- [futures composition, free code camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/futures-made-easy-with-scala-da1beb3bb281/)

Comment: Nice solution and the way of your explanation is simply super .. :)